# How to change background colour in Fscalender customize Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fscalendar

I am trying to change background colour of weekdays and set current date border like below screen shot.

[image: ScreenShot]

My screen shot:

[image]

Team, please let me know how to change background colour and set border colour Any help would be greatly appreciated. Looking forward to hear from you.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @Frankenstein i m trying to change from mainstory board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, change background color of FSCalendar to clear.
2. Add a custom view (background gray) and place it below the calendar and add constraints.
3. Set weekday textcolor to white.

**Main Storyboard**

[image: Screen Shot]

As for modifying today appearance, please download the FSCalendar Example-swift project and check DelegateAppearanceViewController to have a better understanding on how to modify the overall appearance.

**Delegate Appearance**

[image: Screen Shot]